# Why test and training dataset should have same number of columns(variables)?

Tags: machine-learning

Why can't i train  the model with specific number of varaibles and test it with more or less variables. (i know i will get error when i do this). But what is the resaon behind this?

The main concept of ML is ablity to generalise. Why can't it generalise in such scenarios?

Any theoretical explanations?

Comment: Hi welcome. Hint: normally rows correspond to observations, and columns to variables (aka features). – *Reviewer*

Answer (score 1):

You are training a machine learner to identify patterns in your (training) data. If you later incorporate data it has never encountered before it has no idea what to do with it (it literally is seeing this information for the first time).

Think of it as reading Chinese, while you've only learned English. Sure there's a lot of info in the Chinese text but there's no way for you to understand it without learning (at least a little bit).

Even if it is as simple as a linear correlation, without prior knowledge it will just see a single value for a single case and have no information of how that individual value relates to the thing you want to predict.

I think it's important to know that the machine learner typically looks at individual cases and not at the data as a whole.

Example:
*We trained a machine learner to understand that a high value in column A + a low value in column B equals a high value in our predicted column Z.
If we present data with an additional column C to the machine learner, it will not have learned how this value relates to the value in column Z (or how it relates to the other columns), so it will not be able to make use of it.*

Time series & RNN:
As discussed in the comments. If the additional columns only represent more of the same data (for example, a varying number of values representing the same thing, such as bitcoin values). Then it is possible to use certain algorithms to analyse these. Using RNN's for example it is possible to "slide" over time series data and analyse different data of different lengths this way. However, this all assumes the data represents the same thing.

Comment: So each and every input involves in mapping the input to output during training phase.  So more or less during testing  phase won't work.

Comment: Correct. In a very simplistic example, we trained the algorithm to know that: a high value in column A + a low value in column B equals a high value in our predicted column Z. Now if we then add a column D, it hasn't learned to know how a high or low value contributes to the value of column Z.

Comment: But it seems there is a possibilty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066753/how-can-i-use-different-sizes-of-training-data-and-test-data-and-different-batch  with RNN

Comment: The question you linked to refers to batch_size, which is the number of records/rows that is being trained/predicted if I'm not mistaken. This is easier than a different number of columns as the data actually represents the same type of information. When working with time series data it is possible to analyse a varying amount of columns, indeed when using an RNN for example. However this implies that the columns all represent the same thing (e.g. bitcoin value at some time point). This would not work if additional columns represent an unknown type of information.